# Error HTTP 504 When load image form URL with picasso android after ssl issue in Retrofit

Tags: android, picasso

Initially, Images are loaded with Picasso, worked fine.After Rectified the SSL certificate issue in Retrofit, other things are working fine. But Image not loaded.
But, the image can be shown correctly in the browser.

```
com.squareup.picasso.NetworkRequestHandler$ResponseException: HTTP 504
```

I have tried `Network security configuration` in Manifest and

https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/1896 also

Any idea about this??

Code for your Reference

Dependency

```
implementation "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828"
```

Loading Image

```
public void LoadImageWithPicasso(final Context context, SimpleDraweeView sdView, String url) {
            try {
                if (!url.isEmpty()) {
                    Picasso
                            .get()
                            .load(url)
                            .resize(600, 400) // resizes the image to these dimensions (in pixel)
                            .centerInside()
                            .into(sdView, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess() {
                                    System.out.println("SUCCESS--------------------------------->");
                                }
                                @Override
                                public void onError(Exception e) {
                                    System.out.println("FAILURE--------------------------------->"+e);
                                }
                            });
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is the URL the image you are fetching `HTTP` instead of `HTTPS` ?

Comment: Yes. I am fetching images from HTTPS. how can load images in this case?

Comment: Then it is not related to the device itself. `HTTP 504` stands for `Gateway Time-out` so it is probably a server-related issue.

Comment: But, the image can be shown correctly in the browser.

Code for your reference.

implementation "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828"

 Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(simpleDrawableBanner);

Comment: Well, you don't need to use Picasso. You can always use Glide. They have pretty much the same usage but Glide's performance is better. Maybe try that one.